# Downloading file from api url clicking a download link (a href download) in a react app does not work

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

i am trying to download a file from url from an api end point using a href download in a react app created with CRA.
e.g

`<a href="/api/downloads/file.pdf" download>click to download</a>`

it works if i right click on the link and do a 'save link as' .

On clicking the link gives a 302 Found status from the request.

i tried using file-saver 'saveAs' with URI, it gives the same result.

also tried

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(link); 
link.download=filename;
link.href = "/api/downloads/file.pdf";
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

with same result.
how can i get this working?
TIA

Comment: Well 302 is this :
The 302 status code is a redirection message that occurs when a resource or page you're attempting to load has been temporarily moved to a different location

So it sounds like its more of an issue about the file location... could be a rights issue to the directory location, could be a root issue or maybe you are using virtual directories .  What happens if you hardcode the full direct link like "https:\\www.website.com\file.zip" ?

Comment: Some attempts would be like:
link.href = "api/downloads/file.pdf";     <--- might not need the backslash
link.href = "../api/downloads/file.pdf";  <--- might need ... before to go back a dir
link.href = "www.website.com/api/downloads/file.pdf";   <-- try a full directory